# Fabric can't be initialised after adding Twitter Kit 3.1.0

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, twitterkit, fabric-digits

So Twitter kit is now not par of Fabric and is now standalone component. I was not using Twitter kit before now I want to use so had to include its dependency. But after adding it, seems like Fabric initialisation is broken.
I used to init Fabric like this

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme).build());
```

But now Fabric can’t be initialised as `TwitterCore` class is now not extending from `Kit`. Basically Fabric’s `with` method signature is something like this `with(Context context, Kit... kits)` but since `TwitterCore` is not extending from `Kit`, `with` method won’t accept it. I tried removing `TwitterCore` from list of Kits passed in `with` method but got this exception

```
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: Referenced Kit was null, does the kit exist?
```

What is the right way to init Fabric with Digits and Crashlytics now that Twitter Kit is not part of Fabric? Can someone provide snippet? It is not accepting `TwitterCore` as a `Kit` and I guess that is why exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Here's how I initialize Crashlytics and Digits in Swift and Obj-c. Please note that Digits is being replaced with Firebase Auth and **will no longer work as of Sept 30th**. You should migrate to Firebase Auth or another service, and ship  before that

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Digits());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Digits.self])

    return true
}
```

Obj-C:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Digits class]]];
    //[self logUser];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `TwitterCore` is no longer required in Fabric init?

Comment: No, that hasn't been required for a while when using Digits, but the change was backwards compatible.

Comment: I get this when I try to initialise Fabric without TwitterCore. `io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: Referenced Kit was null, does the kit exist?`. Works if I pass TwitterCore to it. Any idea?

Comment: What references do you have to Twitter Kit in your info.plist?

Comment: Not sure i got the question. but here is my init code `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme).build(), new TweetUi());`. If I remove TwitterCore from it. I get above exception.

Comment: Gotcha, are you passing in an API key prior to the Fabric init?

Comment: I don't think i'm passing API key to anything before init. I create `authConfig`  like this  `TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
`. which is passed to TwitterCore. and like I said before, If i don't pass TwitterCore as a Kit to Fabric init, I get that exception. It's weird.

Comment: Hmm, strange. My keys are in an info.plist instead of creating the AuthConfig, but I did pull Twitter via Fabric out of my test app.